# Download all images from the folder in server to local

Tags: android, android-layout, wamp

I am new to android.

A folder having n numbers of images in server, I need to download either the folder or all images at a same URL and save it in local memory. I am using WAMP as a server and service is in php.

Comment: It can be done. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Basically I dont know how to do. Other thing is i need not to bring single file i need steps to bring all files in that particular folder name. (ie) *.png or *.JPG like versa

Answer (score 2):

<
?php

$num_files = count(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/*'));

echo $num_files;

?>

use this code if you want count of the files in the folder.

rename images to same prefix, i.e. image0, image1, etc..

thanks to nostra13, use Universal Image loader
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

run the image loader and show all the images in a loop.